# BigPictureStyle Notification not working in AndroidX

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

Code:
here is the code to popup notification on button click

```
 notificationbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "noti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),OrderTrack.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),(int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),i,0);

                    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.half_bicycle);
                    Notification builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(),"1")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.half_bicycle)
                            .setContentTitle("title")
                            .setContentText("Text")
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                    .bigPicture(bitmap)
                                    .bigLargeIcon(null))
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                            .build();


                    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(getContext())
                            .setContentTitle("New photo from ")
                            .setContentText("subject")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.half_bicycle)
                            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                            .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                                    .bigPicture(bitmap))
                            .build();
                }
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
                notificationManager.notify(101, notif);
            });

Here I am trying to use BigPictureSt
```

yle notification. I hava tried two variation of code. But both doesn't give any result/notification.

All the above code is inside a fragment.Is this a reason why it's not working?

I have set the App style to NoActionBar.Is this a reason why it's not working?

Please answer this questions with a proper solution !!!!

Adding the Following code doesn't solve the problem

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
                    notificationManager.notify(101, notif);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine and there is nothing wrong with it but most importantly you forgot to show the notification itself i.e you are not using the objects that are created.

So show the notification like this...

```
 NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
 notificationManager.notify(101, notif);//101 is notification id
```

EDIT:

If you are targetting Android Oreo and above you need to create the channels for notification like this. Use this function to create notification channel and set this channel id on a notification while creating it...

```
String channelId = "some_channel_id";



   private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Complete code:

```
notificationbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           createNotificationChannel(); //Create notification channel

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "noti", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),OrderTrack.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),(int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),i,0);

                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.half_bicycle);
                Notification builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(),"1")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.half_bicycle)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentText("Text")
                        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID) // Channel Id 
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                .bigPicture(bitmap)
                                .bigLargeIcon(null))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .build();


                Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(getContext())
                        .setContentTitle("New photo from ")
                        .setContentText("subject")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.half_bicycle)
                        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID) // Channel Id 
                        .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                                .bigPicture(bitmap))
                        .build();

     NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
     notificationManager.notify(101, notif);//101 is notification id
            }
        });
```

For more info visit this : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: Adding The following code doesn't solve the problem

Comment: `NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
                notificationManager.notify(101, notif);`